# Besamim on a Cinnamon Bun or Danish

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, havdalah, motzei-shabbos

Motzei Shabbos when making Havdala one realizes he has no cloves, cinnamon sticks or any other spice to make the Beracha (blessing on fragerences) *Borei Minei Besamim*. Can the person take a cinnamon bun or Danish and make the Beracha of *Borei Minei Besamim* on them?

Sources please.

Answer (score 3):

The Beis Yosef Orach chaim 297 quotes an opinion which the Magein Avraham 297,1 supports, that one can make a Brocho of  Borei minei Besamim on smelling a Regular bun that emits a nice smell when its hot - Though the Aruch Hashulchan Orach Chaim 297,5 mentions that this is not the practiced Minhag:

> יש אומרים דאפילו על פת חם מבדילין (עיין ב"י ומג"א), ולא שמענו מי שעשה כן

Since the Cinamon ontop the bun emits a nice natural smell and it is a spice, even those that argue bread alone is not suficient a cinamon bun is fit for saying *Borei minei Besamim* (the Mishna Brura 297,1 1 says we make Borei Minei Besamim even on products from bark or the leaves) even though the cinamon bun is for food purposes, though ideally have a set aside uniquely for smelling Besamim (Mishna Brura 297,4 10).